# Soy Sauce storage container

Tags: storage-method, sauce

I use a fair bit of Soy Sauce for cooking as well as the occasional Chinese take away. My question is fairly simple. Can I store Soy Sauce in a glass vinegar type shaker narrow neck bottle that's not sealed as it has a 1/16 inch hole in top plastic cap. If I can store in that bottle, is it best in a cupboard or refrigerator. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Soy sauce is extremely salty, which will inhibit growth of pathogens; [Eat by date](http://www.eatbydate.com/other/condiments/how-long-does-soy-sauce-last-shelf-life/) suggests 2-3 years, once opened, if kept refrigerated.

With the small hole, better safe than sorry.  I would recommend keeping it in the refrigerator.

If you are not going to use it for a longer time, give it a better seal by placing plastic wrap over opening.  Depending on the exact nature of the container, you may be able to remove the top, place plastic wrap over the opening, and then replace the cap.